# Correct way to run a continuously called method in own thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm calling methode doSomething() continuously with a thread.sleep(100). This happens in on the UIThread, so the UIthread gets unresponsive. What is the correct way in Android to run the method doSomething() or the entire someobject in a seperate thread?

```
public void loop(){
 while(true){
  someObject.doSomething();
  try {
       Thread.sleep(100);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Right now i'm using

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          someObject.doSomething();

    }
 }).start();
```

This obviously creates a different thread for each iteration. I don't think this is the correct way. What is the correct way in Android?

Comment: create a seperate thread class and use looper.....

Comment: Creating un-stoppable/un-interruptable threads is not a good idea though...

Answer (score 6):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
           try {
               Thread.sleep(100);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           someObject.doSomething();
       }
    }
 }).start();
```

Since run never returns, the thread will never end and will loop forever.  It will call doSomething roughly every 100 ms (as close as sleep will  get, which isn't exact).

Comment: But doSomething() still runs on UIThread. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Not if its in a runnable inside a Thread like this.  The Runnable passed to the thread is run on the Thread, that's the entire point.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own Thread class, with Looper and Handler, posting your doSomething every 100ms:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
  private Handler myHandler;

  @Override
  public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.post(doSomethingRunnable);
  }
  Runnable doSomethingRunnable = new Runnnable{
    doSomething();  //or myHandler.postDelayed() first for greater accuracy, but only if doSomething doesnt take too long
    myHandler.postDelayed(doSomethingRunnable, 100);
  };
  doSomething(){
  thisStuff(thatStuff());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). `doInBackground()` is called on a background thread and will not block UI. This is the preferred way for doing stuff on background threads.

For a long running task. You can use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) and put your background code in `onHandleIntent`

You can use a basic thread but it may be hard to manage. You can read more about threads in android  [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)